# Check if account is locked out

Tags: windows, active-directory, graphical-user-interface

How can I check if an account is locked in Active Directory?

I would prefer to use the GUI, but I can use the CLI if that's the only option. I checked the "Account" tab under Properties, and I see an "Unlock account" option, but it not clear if that means the account is currently locked.

Comment: For posterity sake, you should mention which forest/domain version you are on.  Over time additional tools/features/GUIs change and answers may no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Using Powershell:

```
get-aduser bob -Properties lockedout |select lockedout

lockedout
---------
    False
```

Comment: An empty value indicates that you omitted the `-Properties` argument (or have a typo in it). The `lockedout` attribute is not loaded by default and must be specified explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

### Active Directory Administrative Center

On the user list, click the arrow in the top right corner. Then click Add
criteria. Then click Users with enabled but locked accounts (I cannot post
images directly, so here is a link):

https://serverspace.us/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/63_uad411.png

Then click Add.

https://serverspace.us/support/help/how-to-manage-user-accounts-in-active-directory-part-4-finding-locked-out-accounts-and-unlocking-them

### Active Directory Users and Computers

Select View > Advanced. The Attribute Editor tab on the user account shows
every attribute. AD Users and Computers can show any attribute of an object,
including lockoutTime.

Comment: AD Users and Computers can show any attribute of an object, including lockoutTime.

Comment: Select View > Advanced. The Attribute Editor tab on the user account shows every attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your user (AD users and computers) and click on "reset password".
You don't have to reset the password but the Account lockout status will be shown. [Screenshot "reset password" window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NIhP.png)

Answer (score -1):

Check out this tool from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15201

It will help you figure out which Domain Controller to look on for more info in the logs as well.